# Pass environment variable through to Angular app

Tags: angularjs, gulp

I'd like to configure my gulp webserver task to pass an environment variable into the angular app. Each team member has his own VM running the API and the variable would instruct the Angular app of the base API url. I'm trying to eliminate the need for every team member to remember to edit the config file after every TFS update.

I thought of simply setting a response header via middleware, but javascript cannot see response headers for the current page - only those of XHR responses.

So I try initializing the config service by performing a HEAD request against the web root, but this requires resolving a $http promise which requires adding a resolve to the route config to ensure it gets resolved before something tries to use it.

I tried just injecting a cookie via middleware and reading it with the $cookies service, but Internet Explorer apparently doesn't see 'localhost' as a valid domain name for cookies and does not read them.

So what other ways are there to allow an environment variable (or other form of local config) to be passed into the angular app?

Comment: is the angular app itself hosted on a server capable of some server side code? You could render the index.html page itself through node or php or whatever and just attach it to `window` in a header script tag or something.

Comment: Ultimately, yes, but this effort is for local development in which the app is hosted locally via node (gulp-webserver). I'm trying to have just a minimal bit of code in the config service that will check for the presence of the URL "environment" variable and use it if present. I don't want gulp to be rewriting source files for this.

Comment: I can't really think of anything else... but it will be a minimal amount of code with a plugin like [gulp-replace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-replace)

Answer (score 0):

We have solved this problem in many ways for different situations.

1. We don't use the base URL but just relative "/folder/resource".
2. We have an HttpHandler that resolves files with custom extension i.e. ".xyz". Then we have a file named "config.xyz" which is just a JavaScript  file with something like:
   {
      baseUrl: [BASE_URL]
   }
   When the handler is asked to provide this file, the handler reads the file and does the replacements and then serve its content.
3. Use the one fake name for the server that serves the API. I.e: thisismylocalfake and then ask developers to configure their hosts file in system32
4. Have a gulp tasks that, when you compile the application, takes one config.js file and uses the machine name to replace a tag like in option 2.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding middleware to the **gulp-webserver** to intercept a request for our config service file. Then I used **gulp-replace** and **gulp-respond** to inject the url from the environment variable directly in the stream. No files edited, technically and it works without having to have any sort of dev-specific code in the project.